# How to access ApplicationResource properties in context initialization method?

Tags: java, properties, struts2, httpcontext

I am using quartz scheduler which runs after every 15 minutes .
So the parameter 15(interval ) i am defining in ApplicationResource.properties file
I have listener class defined as

```
public class QuartzSchedulerListener extends ActionSupport implements ServletContextListener
```

So in `public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent context)`
in this method i am trying to get parameter value using ActionSupports -- getText() method

```
getText("INTERVAL_TIME");
```

but i am getting error

Can please somebody tell me whats going with the code or any other alternative way to access the properties of ApplicationResources file

Thanks in advance

Comment: i am not sure why you trying to use S2 Action support class here??

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi I found the getText() seems to useful but i was wrong its giving me exception & i know this class used for actions ,
Please tell me what is other way to access properties?

Comment: one more thing which i am not sure, why you want to read this property since you can configure Scheduler for this triggering time, else i suggest you to read the property file as a resource in your Listner or least which is not recommend put that property in your custom quartz property file since Quartz tend to read this property file on server startup

Comment: where did you place the ApplicationResource.properties. can you post the error that you are having.